# Why does my android studio EditText view not display input, output, or the hint?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

My EditText does not work like the videos and articles I have found. The EditText does not show what the user inputted at the time of input or when I tell the output to show there, the hint I assigned it also does not show up. Right now I have the output going to a TextView but can greatly reduce lines of code if I can get the EditText working properly. I am new to this and have troubles understanding. Thank you for the help.

Here is the xml file:

```
//DOES NOT SHOW INPUT AT TIME OF INPUT, OR WHEN TOLD TOLD BY OUTPUT. HINT DOES NOT SHOW EITHER-------
<EditText
android:id="@+id/MetalCounter"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:ems="10"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:hint="0"
android:textColorHint="#000000"
android:inputType="number"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ResourceSubmitButton" />

 //is put in top left corner for testing purposes---------------------------------
<TextView
android:id="@+id/MetalResult"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:text=""
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="15sp"
 />
```

and here is the java file:

```
package com.example.game;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// These are the global variables
EditText MetalCounter;
TextView MetalResult;
Button ResourceSubmitButton;
int Metal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //to get from user input and into variable form
    MetalCounter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MetalCounter);
    MetalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MetalResult);
    ResourceSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ResourceSubmitButton);

    //Submit button
    ResourceSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //to receive and show the inputted values into the MetalResult TextView
            MetalResult.setText(MetalCounter.getText().toString());
   

            //This is a test to see if the result would show up but does not
            Metal = Integer.parseInt(MetalCounter.getText().toString());
            MetalCounter.setText(MetalCounter.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the problem lies here in this part

```xml
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:ems="10"
android:textSize="15sp"
```

These attributes are not well-defined because you have set the `layout_margin` to 4dp which causes the view to shrink. so instead of having a width of 40dp, now you have a width of 32dps, similarly you have a height of only 12dps which is very small and doesn't match with the selected `textSize`

So, my suggestion is changing the width and height attributes to wrap_content as follows

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and you can keep everything else as it's.

### Remarks

- Consider changing your variables to follow the `camelCase` convention

```java
// Before
EditText MetalCounter;
TextView MetalResult;

//After
EditText metalCounter;
TextView metalResult;
```

- Change the hint color's opacity in order to differentiate it from the text itself
- If you still have a problem so it may be due to the constraints in the bottom. If so, please post the full layout file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not understand that the margin came from the width and that height needed to bigger then text size. Thank you for teaching me. It works propperly now, however I can not use wrap_content for the width because it makes the box really big. Also what does the " android:ems="10" " attribute mean and how do I limit the EditText view to 3 digits? Thank you.

Comment: When you set the `ems` property to 10 it means that the `EditText` width will fit only for 10 characters even if the number of characters exceeded 10. However, if you need to specify the maximum number of characters that the user is allowed to enter you can use `android:maxLength="10"`